# Looking For : Data Selection Method

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am a beginner in sql ... i search accross the web to find a solution for my problem but i could not found any suitable answer .

i have the following tables in sql server database ::

**Room**                           **Block**                     **BoxSet**

**Room** idField , RoomNumber

**Block**   RoomID : foreign key to Room Table

**BoxSet** BlockID : foreign key to Block Table

i have been trying to find a way to select records in BoxSet Table according to Room Table RoomNumber Field.

for example:i want to select all records in BoxSet Table which belongs to RoomNumber=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT BS.* 

FROM Room R 
INNER JOIN Block B ON R.RoomId = B.RoomId 
INNER JOIN BoxSet BS ON B.BlockId = BS.BlockId

WHERE R.RoomNumber = 1;
```

This is a very basic usage of the [`JOIN` functionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) present in every relational database.

Comment: Since it is homework only giving a general example would be better IMHO. :)

Comment: @TimMedora: the join to Block should be on the RoomId.  The assumption that Block has a BlockId column is probably valid, but it would have been nice if he had said so explicitly.

Comment: @juergend - I can go either way. Sometimes the best way to learn is to see a problem you have been struggling with visualized and solved and then to experiment with the results.

Comment: @jmoreno - good catch, fixed the incorrect column in the join.

Comment: it is not homework..could you please give an explanation for your code

Comment: @samih - the code simply joins the tables together based on the keys that they share. Because all of your tables are directly or indirectly related, you can write a query with information from only one table and find related rows in other tables.

Comment: @TimMedora:thank you...your code solve my problem..is there any good resource you know to learn more about Tables Joins with examples..i really want to learn the joins very well!

Comment: @samih - check the Wikipedia article I linked and also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx for SQL Server specifically.